# Web Driver Exception

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, geckodriver

This is the code I used.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://172.16.16.16/24online/servlet/E24onlineHTTPClient")
```

This exception occurs when I try to run a script for firefox. 
Please help me with this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Labs\Ion\pwner.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py",
line 152, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", l
ine 98, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", l
ine 188, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", l
ine 256, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py"
, line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unable to find a matchin
g set of capabilities
```

Comment: Can you show us your code block and research please? Thanks

Comment: Selenium, GeckoDriver, Mozilla Firefox versions please. Thanks

Comment: Selenium 3.4.3; GeckoDriver 0.18; Firefox 54.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading Firefox should resolve the problem, and you can try to upgrade selenium as well if you want to make sure...

Comment: i have latest firefox latest firefox

Comment: What is your FF version?

Comment: My Firefox is 54.0.1

Answer (score 0):

While you work with `Selenium 3.4.3`, `geckodriver v.0.18.0`, `Mozilla Firefox 53.0` using `Python` the following code block would open up the desired url:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary(r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com')
```